# splitting a text in text file by new line

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

```
import java.io.*;
public class Wordcount {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        String[] splited = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("sample.txt"));
            String read = null;
            while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {
                splited = read.split("systemSerialNumber:");
                for (String part : splited) {
                    System.out.println(part);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("There was a problem: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            in.close();

        }

        System.out.println(splited[3]);
    }
}
```

"sample.txt" file contains below text.

```
"2018-10-16 19:54:26.691 [RawEventProcessor (2/2)] ERROR com.qolsys.iqcloud.processing.operators.RawEventProcessor1  - processRawPanelEvent():: SerialNumber systemSerialNumber: QV01D173700428AD is not mapped to any meid. {}",2
"2018-10-16 19:54:27.074 [RawEventProcessor (2/2)] ERROR com.qolsys.iqcloud.processing.operators.RawEventProcessor1  - processRawPanelEvent():: SerialNumber systemSerialNumber: QV01D173700428AD is not mapped to any meid. {}",2
"2018-10-16 19:54:27.293 [RawEventProcessor (2/2)] ERROR com.qolsys.iqcloud.processing.operators.RawEventProcessor1  - processRawPanelEvent():: SerialNumber systemSerialNumber: QV01D173700428AD is not mapped to any meid. {}",2
"2018-10-16 19:54:27.296 [RawEventProcessor (2/2)] ERROR com.qolsys.iqcloud.processing.operators.RawEventProcessor1  - processRawPanelEvent():: SerialNumber systemSerialNumber: QV01D173700428AD is not mapped to any meid. {}",2
```

I am getting error that array index out of bound exception.
and why i am getting this exception i don't know even after splitting also all the text file data is stored at one index of array. Remaining are empty.

Stack Trace :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
>     at Task1.Wordcount.main(Wordcount.java:29)

Comment: I think that `BufferedReader#readLine` should already be able to correctly pick up the newlines.  What is the problem with your code?

Comment: when i am printing splited[1] at the end of program it is giving array  index out of bound exception

Comment: Please describe the issue you are having. Like Tim mentioned above, JAVA supports reading lines OOB.

Comment: Probably because `\r` does not occur in the line(s).  So, the result of `String#split` is that just the `[0]` entry has the the entire line.  Again, what are you trying to do here?

Comment: Actually  i want to count a specific text is repeated how many times in a file.For that i used splitting and after that i want to  store splitted parts into map and then i can count.So at begining only i have strucked.

Comment: Why don't you use the `Files.lines` method? It's much more elegant.

Comment: Your code works fine, I'm able to print out the indexes of the array `splited`

Comment: Nicholas K ---- Are you getting that splited[1] part

Comment: i am getting array index out of bound exception.

Comment: yes i'm able to print it out without any issues. Can you copy paste your stack-trace in the question by editing it?

Comment: I am also getting but only first line of text file is splitted and what about remaining.Are you getting all the data of the splitted text file or only first line

Comment: I will show my stack trace. wait

Comment: Naturally just the first line, as you are not storing the values for the rest in any index.

Comment: sorry,I didn't understood can u explain briefly.

Comment: I've added an answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the result has length 2. The last line might be empty.

```
Path path = Paths.get("sample.txt");
Files.lines(path, Charset.defaultCharset())
    .forEach(line -> {
        String[] splitted = read.split("systemSerialNumber:");
        if (splitted.length == 2) {
            ...
        }
    });
```

As unrelated info:

```
        String[] splitted = read.split("systemSerialNumber:", 2);
```

would limit the result to at most 2 elements, in case of `"systemSerialNumber:"` occurring more than once.